# Asyncio: task got bad yield?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

My code here always drops an error message which neither google, neither chatgpt are unable to explain:

```
import asyncio
import udiskie
import udiskie.config
import udiskie.udisks2

async def main():
    device = '/dev/mmcblk0p1'
    config = udiskie.config.Config.from_file()
    udisks = await udiskie.udisks2.Daemon.create()
    await udisks.connect()
    try:
        await udisks.unmount(device)
    finally:
        await udisks.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When being run:

```
test.py", line 9, in main
    udisks = await udiskie.udisks2.Daemon.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/udiskie/udisks2.py", line 699, in create
    proxy = await dbus.connect_service(*service)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/udiskie/dbus.py", line 288, in connect_service
    proxy = await proxy_new_for_bus(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/udiskie/dbus.py", line 279, in proxy_new_for_bus
    result = await future
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/udiskie/async_.py", line 92, in __await__
    return (yield self)
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <udiskie.async_.Future object at 0x7fbb12c100>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [udiskie Github wiki](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/wiki/Python-API):

> One frequently asked question is whether udiskie exposes a Python API
> that can be used inside Python scripts.
>
> Because of the way that udiskie is implemented, there is currently no
> convenient Python API. This is mostly due to the fact that udiskie is
> based on a homebrewn async layer. (I would prefer too to have a Python
> API that is useful for outsiders and may reconsider)

Using udiskie the way you are trying to use it is **unsupported** and **not expected to work**. udiskie is not compatible with asyncio. It uses its own async implementation.